# SQL Month comparison to declared variable

Tags: sql, db2

```
select 
sc.locationid, --here to get a result
(
   if month(date()) between 8 and 12 then @semTerm = 'S1'
   else @semTerm = 'S2'
   end if
)as @semTerm

from student_class sc
where @semTerm = sc.semester
;
```

In db2 student management system. Read only access.  Desired outcome is If Jan thru June, S2 else if Aug thru Dec, S1.  Trying to setup a variable based on the current date stamp where the month is segregated then assigned to a variable then compared against a column in student_class table.

Have tried case statements as well with no luck.  Unable to declare @semTerm without error above select statement.  Looked at where clause solution also. Am I out in left field?  Seems simple but struggling with the syntax.  Part of a larger statement with locationID as one column in student_class.

Comment: Which type of DB2 server are you using?  DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS?

Comment: DB2 LUW, sorry for not being explicity.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use an `IF` statement in a simple `SELECT` statement, you must use `CASE`:

```
select 
    sc.locationid, --here to get a result
    case 
      when month(current date) between 8 and 12 then 'S1'
      when month(current date) between 1 and 6  then 'S2'
      else ''
    end as semTerm 
from 
    student_class sc
```

If you want to find only the students for the current semester, then you would want to move the `CASE` statement into the `WHERE` clause:

```
select 
    sc.locationid, --here to get a result
    sc.semester,
    ...
from 
    student_class sc
where 
    sc.semester = case 
                    when month(current date) between 8 and 12 then 'S1'
                    when month(current date) between 1 and 6  then 'S2'
                    end
```

Comment: Will review your answer today and test.  I looked at a case statement as well, most likely bad syntax on my part.  Appreciate your concise answer, will work on this a bit later this morning.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  Although I did not use this code, reviewing it has assisted in learning.  Appreciate you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression is generally the way to implement conditional logic in a `SELECT` statement.  However, it would be more efficient if you didn't have to recalculate it on every row, right?

One approach would be to "precalculate" it in a common table expression, and join to that as your selection criteria:

```
with v (semester) as
( values 
    case 
      when month(current date) > 7 then 'S1'
      when month(current date) < 7 then 'S2'
                                   else null
    end
)
select 
    sc.locationid, 
    sc.semester,
    ...
from 
    student_class sc
join
    v                on  sc.semester = v.semester;
```

**OR**

If you you find that this current semester value would be useful in many other places, another approach could be to create a 'global session variable' to hold the value. (except on z/OS)

```
create or replace variable
    v_sememster  char(2)
      default 
        case 
          when month(current date) > 7
            then 'S1'
          when month(current date) < 7
            then 'S2'
          else   null
        end;
```

Then you can have a very simple query:

```
select 
    sc.locationid, 
    sc.semester,
    ...
from 
    student_class sc
where 
    sc.semester = v_semester;
```

Comment: The syntax of your first example is what I've seen in the ddl.  Using DbViz Pro to query. This is good to see as this syntax eluded me also.  Appreciate all responses. Will work on this later this morning.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Used your first example above.  This is what I was initially trying to do and it makes more logical sense to me.  With some tweaking to reflect actual dbase values this worked great!  Thank you so much! Including the join above, the query has 6 joins.   The entire sql query will be used in a vbs script that is already written but functioning with sql from views.  Had a rush project that required using views initially.  Now the entire process will be automated and work year around as requested.  Again, my most humblest of thank you's!